# Maven / Firebase - Cannot find symbol: variable Firestore Client

Tags: java, firebase, maven, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect to Firebase within my Java project, managed with Maven. I am following [Firebase's Getting Started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#java_1) exactly to set up my development environment and initialize Cloud Firestore. This is what my pom.xml and myClass.java looks like.

My dependency in pom.xml:

```
   <dependencies>
        <!-- This dependency is added for Firebase usage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

My myClass.java:

```
package ca.uhn.fhir.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext;
import ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.RestfulServer;
import ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.interceptor.ResponseHighlighterInterceptor;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import java.io.*;


@WebServlet("/*")
public class Example02_SimpleRestfulServer extends RestfulServer {

    @Override
    protected void initialize() throws ServletException {
        // Create a context for the appropriate version
        setFhirContext(FhirContext.forR4());
        
        // Register resource providers
        // Calls the constructor on the resource provider class? 
        registerProvider(new Example01_PatientResourceProvider());
        
        // Format the responses in nice HTML
        registerInterceptor(new ResponseHighlighterInterceptor());
    
        try {   
        // Initialize Firebase
        // Use a service account
        String credentials_path = "/my/path/dfdfdfdfd93.json";
        InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(credentials_path);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        
        Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, I run into the error:
`cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   variable FirestoreClient`. I have tried adding other related dependencies as shown below, but they are not found/don't seem to fix the problem. I think I am following the Firebase tutorial exactly, so what might I be doing wrong? Why is the FirestoreClient not recognized but many of the other variables are?

```
        <!-- Attempting to fix errors (this doesn't seem to do anything) -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-firestore -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- Not found -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-firestore -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-firestore</artifactId>
            <version>18.1.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!--Not found-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-core -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-core</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.2</version>
        </dependency> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you did not import the `FirestoreClient` class, so add the following import to your `Example02_SimpleRestfulServer` class and it will be fixed:

```
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
```

**NOTE**: This should also be in the example in the documentation example you shared, I would recommend you to open a Bug Report in [Google's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) for they to fix that documentation, if you'd like.

Comment: It compiled, thank you so much! So I know how to debug better, how did you know that this import statement was missing?

Comment: The error message was stating that it Could not find that simbol, in other words, it had not been initialized, in fact it had not been declared before, so I thought, this is a static method, so the only thing that could have cause this error was a missing import, and that was it.